# Connect to H2 database using IntelliJ database client

Tags: grails, intellij-idea, h2

My Grails app uses a h2 database in dev mode (the default behaviour for Grails apps). The DB connection settings in `DataSource.groovy` are

```
dataSource {
    pooled = true
    jmxExport = true
    driverClassName = "org.h2.Driver"
    username = "sa"
    password = ""
    dbCreate = "create-drop" // one of 'create', 'create-drop', 'update', 'validate', ''
    url = "jdbc:h2:mem:devDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE"
}
```

I'm trying to setup a connection for this database using IntelliJ IDEA's database client tools. I start off creating the connection like so

[image]

Then in the following dialog, I enter the JDBC URL

[image]

And choose all available databases on the "Schemas & Tables" tab.

[image]

The "Test Connection" button indicates success, but as you can see from the red circle, no tables are found. It seems like I've correctly setup a connection to the h2 server, but not the schema itself.

BTW, I try to setup this connection once the app is running, so I'm sure that the schema/tables do actually exist.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I used Mark's recommendations to no avail (use AUTO_SERVER=TRUE, and embedded DB in root directory). I can never seem to browse an H2 db from Intellij. This has become ridiculously difficult.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/64673466/2930427

Answer (score 129):

Your configuration is for an `h2:mem` database. Memory Databases have no tables upon connecting to them, and any & all tables are lost when all the connections are closed. Furthermore, a (named) in memory database is **unique to the JVM process** that opens it. From the [H2 documentation](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#in_memory_databases):

> Sometimes multiple connections to the same in-memory database are required. In this case, the database URL must include a name. Example: jdbc:h2:mem:db1. **Accessing the same database using this URL only works within the same virtual machine and class loader environment.** (Emphasis added)

This means IDEA will create a unique `devDb` in its JVM (and classloader) space and your application will create a unique `devDb` in its JVM (and classloader) space. You can not connect to an in memory database from an external JVM process.

If you want to connect both your application and IntelliJ IDEA (or any other DB tool) to an H2 database at the same time, you will need to either

1. use an embedded database (that writes to a file) in your application and use `Mixed Mode` to allow IntelliJ IDEA (and/or other database tools) to connect to it
2. use a server mode database

See http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#connection_modes for more information.

Comment: for those who wondering how to enable mixed mode: jdbc:h2:~/test;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE (both in app config and idea db manager settings)

Comment: Why does Intellji have a H2 option for connecting to it, if its not possible on the JVM level? Specifically for the mixed mode use?

Answer (score 21):

This article has a great write up on how to set up the IntelliJ database client to connect to an H2 in-memory database if you happen to be using Spring Boot: http://web.archive.org/web/20160513065923/http://blog.techdev.de/querying-the-embedded-h2-database-of-a-spring-boot-application/

Basically, you wrap the in-memory database with a tcp server, then you have an access point to connect with a sql client via remote access.

Answer (score 6):

Try to open http://localhost:8080/dbconsole and fill your jdbc url
[image]

Comment: if you are using spring boot you should have `spring.h2.console.enabled=true
` in `application.properties` file

Comment: http://localhost:8080/h2-console url is  working  not above mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

During development you can use grails [h2 dbconsole](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.3.1/guide/conf.html#3.3.5%20Database%20Console)

Comment: The idea is that we want Intellij to give us code hints from the db

Answer (score 3):

Let's imagine you've already created entities (Users, Addresses)

Step 1. In application.yml file add H2 properties.

```
server:
  port: 8080

spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:~/data/parserpalce (for Mac OS)
    username: sa
    password: password
    driver-class-name: org.h2.Driver
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
  h2:
    console:
      enabled: true
```

Step 2. Add H2 Database client
[image]

Step 3. Configure H2 database client properties based on your application.yml properties.
[image]

Step 4. Run the application.

Step 5. Check if tables(Users, Addresses) are created.
[image]

Or you can use H2 console for it in browser:
http://localhost:8080/h2-console

P.S. Do not forget to paste appropriate values in fields!