# Connecting to existing in-memory H2 from different application/process

Tags: java, h2, quarkus, in-memory-database, embedded-database

I have a simple `Quarkus` application that uses an in-memory `H2` database. The JDBC connection string has some custom settings: `jdbc:h2:mem:quarkus_db;DATABASE_TO_LOWER=TRUE;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;MODE=MariaDB`.

I'm trying to connect to the **exact same database from a database manager** — say `DataGrip`. After following the [documentation](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#in_memory_databases), [several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2768450/h2-in-memory-tables-remote-connection) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43256295/how-to-access-in-memory-h2-database-of-one-spring-boot-application-from-another) from `StackOverflow`, and [some blog posts](https://jsoftbiz.wordpress.com/2011/04/30/share-an-h2-in-memory-database-among-several-jvms/), I'm still unable to connect to the same instance and query for any existing data using SQL.

There is something I don't fully understand from the examples. I've seen that initially using a connection like this in the application: `jdbc:h2:mem:quarkus_db`, and while the same it's up and running, then on the other application/process (`DataGrip` in my case) using `jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/mem:quarkus_db` should work, but I fail to see how the first scheme will create a TCP server.

My goal is to verify some data while the application is running. I understand that when using something like `jdbc:h2:mem:*`, everything will be lost after the application stops.

Comment: Possibly related: [*How to access in-memory h2 database from Intellij IDEA*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52388984/642706)

Comment: I think I may have going through several of those, but I don't see anywhere how `Quarkus` is able to start `H2` in "server mode".

Comment: See also [_In-Memory Databases_](https://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#in_memory_databases).