# H2 db not accessible at localhost:8080/h2-console when using webflux

Tags: java, spring, h2, spring-webflux

H2 db is not accessible at `localhost:8080/h2-console` when using `webflux`. I read somewhere that this is available only when developing a Servlet-based application. But I am using Webflux with Netty. So is there a way to see the h2 console in such an application?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I had the same issue, I ended up booting the console server manually on another port:

```java
@Component
@Profile("test") // <-- up to you
public class H2 {

    private org.h2.tools.Server webServer;

    private org.h2.tools.Server tcpServer;

    @EventListener(org.springframework.context.event.ContextRefreshedEvent.class)
    public void start() throws java.sql.SQLException {
        this.webServer = org.h2.tools.Server.createWebServer("-webPort", "8082", "-tcpAllowOthers").start();
        this.tcpServer = org.h2.tools.Server.createTcpServer("-tcpPort", "9092", "-tcpAllowOthers").start();
    }

    @EventListener(org.springframework.context.event.ContextClosedEvent.class)
    public void stop() {
        this.tcpServer.stop();
        this.webServer.stop();
    }

}
```

Then navigate to http://localhost:8082 (without /h2-console).

Comment: Thank you. That will suffice and is perfect for my requirement. Amazed at the way people get over things.

Comment: hi , used same code as above , getting error like  "File not found: h2"

Comment: same issue as @prasannajoshi, "File not found: h2-console", no exceptions or stack trace

Comment: Remove the url path. It's accessible on http://localhost:8082

Comment: You can move the start method to your application class and just start it there inside the main() function and it works. Just access localhost:8082

Comment: @Sp00m thank you for the great solution. Do you know why this problem happens? It's interesting.

Comment: @prasannajoshi don't add 'h2/console' just "http://localhost:8082"

Comment: I cannot seem to get it to work, when i hit localhost:8082, i get the following error: "This site can’t be reached"

Answer (score 3):

I found a library that does exactly the same sp00m described, it may be helpful for somebody. It works out of the box.

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/me.yaman.can/spring-boot-webflux-h2-console

And github page: https://github.com/canyaman/spring-boot-webflux-h2-console