# enable h2 console with Spring Security

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, h2, spring-webflux

I want to use the h2-console in my Spring Boot project with Spring Security enabled. My Config looks like the following, but i cannot reach any of the unauthenticated paths. If i open the console path the Loginprompt apears.

Is there something in the wrong order?

I've tried it the old way with a WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter and it worked, but i want to use the new stuff.

```
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {

        return http
                .csrf().disable()
                .headers().frameOptions().disable().and()
                .authorizeExchange()
                .anyExchange().permitAll()
                .and()
                .httpBasic().and()
                .build();
    }
}
```

I changed the config to the following and the authentication excludes the h2 console like I expected:

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.headers().frameOptions().disable().and()
                .csrf().disable();
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/h2-console/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .permitAll();
    }
}
```

Comment: what happens if you add the following to your security class : .antMatchers("/h2-console/**")  or read this : http://appsdeveloperblog.com/add-h2-database-to-spring-boot-project-with-spring-security/

Comment: Antmatchers only exists in WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter (HttpSecurity), not in WebFlux (ServerHttpSecurity), or did I miss something?

Comment: I tried pathMatcher("/h2-console/**").permitAll(), but that doesn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

H2 console seems to only be available on servlet based servers, and webflux is using jetty which is not a servlet based server.

[h2 no accessible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52949088/h2-db-not-accessible-at-localhost8080-h2-console-when-using-webflux)