# WebFlux and JDBC: H2 console opens with empty schema

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, h2, spring-boot-devtools

I've seen variations of this subject multiple times around, but the answers never solved my case: I've been adding the H2 console to my WebFlux application (Spring Boot 2.6.3) and could connect to it; but **couldn't see any of my tables in my JDBC schema**. Thing is... My controller is working fine and I can retrieve from my endpoint the expected structure and data I did setup into shema.sql et data.sql

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-r2dbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.r2dbc</groupId>
        <artifactId>r2dbc-h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>me.yaman.can</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-webflux-h2-console</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
```

These are my properties : I'm connecting to localhost:8080/h2-console and am being redirected to localhost:8081/ all right

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:pocdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=foobar
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.port=8081
spring.h2.console.path=/h2-console
```

As I said, the connection to the console is OK, **with my "pocdb" schema declared in the login URL**; but I can't see any custom tables in here :-(

I also tried with and without the db url parameters but nothing changes. IF somebody has any clue about what I'm doing wrong, I'd be relieved to here it. Thx

Comment: Does this answer your question? [H2 db not accessible at localhost:8080/h2-console when using webflux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52949088/h2-db-not-accessible-at-localhost8080-h2-console-when-using-webflux)

Comment: Sorry @K.Nicholas but no. I made clear that the console is up and running though; my issue is with no custom table from my schema shown in the UI