# Play / Slick / Evolution is not applied

Tags: scala, playframework, slick

Projektsetup: Intellj ->Play Framework -> H2 inMem DB

I'm trying to get my DB up and running. 
I'm so for that i can click the "Apply this Script now" Button.

After clicking the Apllication starts normally. But when I look into the default DB and the public schema there is nothing there.

I'm opening the DB with the integrated DB Tool from Intellj.

The project is on [GitHub](https://github.com/Bersacker/ChatSystem) 
(I can also post the importent Files if that is better)

When i run the script directly from Console it works as expected.

**How and Where can I check if the Script is executed and where is it executed?**

Answer (score 0):

This answer will fix the Problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28950817/2195551

H2 databases are in memory, and when you try to access it from intelliJ, the IDE will try to access another instance of the in memory database. That's why your app works, but you can't see the tables from IntelliJ.

Mailing List found the Problem [Link to Discussion](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/play-framework/_utsG2xcXV4/discussion)